# Use jquery cookie to remember which div is toggled on page refresh

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggle

How do I set a cookie using jquery to remember which div is toggled and keep it toggled when the page is refreshed?

I have have tried many solutions and almost have it figured out, but I'm getting stuck when setting and retrieving the cookie.

```
My HTML:
<a href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" >Login</a>
<a href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" >Register</a>

<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="display: block">
   default text to be shown when no cookies are set
</div>

<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="display: none">
login form
</div>

<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3" style="display: none"> 
register form       
</div>
```

My script:

```
/************jQuery Cookie**************/
;(function(g){g.cookie=function(h,b,a){if(1<arguments.length&&(!/Object/.test(Object.prototype.toString.call(b))||null===b||void 0===b)){a=g.extend({},a);
if(null===b||void 0===b)a.expires=-1;
if("number"===typeof a.expires){var d=a.expires,c=a.expires=new Date;
c.setDate(c.getDate()+d)}b=""+b;
return document.cookie=[encodeURIComponent(h),"=",a.raw?b:encodeURIComponent(b),a.expires?";
expires="+a.expires.toUTCString():"",a.path?";
path="+a.path:"",a.domain?";
domain="+a.domain:"",a.secure?";
secure":
""].join("")}for(var a=b||{},d=a.raw?function(a){return a}:decodeURIComponent,c=document.cookie.split("; "),e=0,f;f=c[e]&&c[e].split("=");
e++)if(d(f[0])===h)return d(f[1]||"");
return null}})(jQuery);

if ($.cookie('showDiv') == 'newboxes2'){
 newboxes2.show();
}

if ($.cookie('showDiv') == 'newboxes3'){
 newboxes3.show();
}

function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
$('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
         $(this).show(200);
         $.cookie('showDiv', thechosenone);
    }
    else {
         $(this).hide(600);
    }
});
}
```

If the cookie code isn't formatted properly, there is a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/CQFJ4/ but that fiddle doesn't do what I need, I just borrowed the cookie code.

The place I'm getting stuck is **setting the cookie in the each loop using $(this)**
and then **recalling that cookie when the page is refreshed**
Thanks for the help I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `this` inside a string, it won't be interpreted as an identifier, it will just be those four characters. You would need to concatenate the id from the element into the string, so this would work with your current code:

```
$.cookie($(this).attr('id') + '.showDiv', 'visible');
```

However, every cookie value is sent back an forth between the server and the browser in *every* request, and the space allowed for cookies for a domain is limited to a few kilobytes, so you should keep the cookies as small as possible. Use a single cookie and put the identify of the visible element in the value instead:

```
$.cookie('showDiv', thechosenone);
```

Then you check the value when displaying the elements:

```
if ($.cookie('showDiv') == 'newboxes2'){
  newboxes2.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I edited my code above to include your suggestions and still can't get it to work on my site. Did I put the code snippets in the right place?

Comment: @user2680557: (When editing the question, add to it rather than changing the original code. Now the answer is hard to understand, because the question seem to already contain the code that was suggested.) To make the code work, you need to put the code that shows the elements after refresh in the `ready` or `load` event. Now the code runs before the elements exist.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. Would I do it something like this?
`$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($.cookie('showDiv') == 'newboxes2'){
    newboxes2.show();
  }
  if ($.cookie('showDiv') == 'newboxes3'){
    newboxes3.show();
  }
}` because that breaks the javascript toggle functionality

Comment: @user2680557: Yes, that looks right, except that would be `$('#newboxes2').show();` instead of `newboxes2.show();` (and the same for the other). You might also want to hide the first `div` when you show any of the other ondes.

Comment: Thanks, I REALLY appreciate your help with this! I tried that and the javascript toggle functionality is still broken when I make those changes. This is the site I'm trying to implement it on if that helps. It's the login form in the sidebar: cropcircleshawaii.com

Comment: @user2680557: You are missing `);` at the end of the ready event. Change the `}` before the `showonlyone` function to `});`.

Comment: Ok that fixed the javascript toggle but it still doesn't remember which div is toggled when I refresh the page.

Comment: @user2680557: The code that uses jQuery has to come after the script tag that includes jQuery.

Comment: Ahhhh got it! THANK YOU so much! I have been stumped on this issue for weeks.

Comment: @user2680557: Tip: bring up the Error Console / Web Console in the browser to see error messages. Javascript errors aren't normally shown to the user.